# What happened to my last StackExchange account?

Tags: support, users

I tried to log in today and StackExchange said it didn't recognize the email I put. Password recovery had the same issue. This was my account https://stackexchange.com/users/2435303/raansu     and one of my questions: [Looking for a way to compress, encrypt, split, and upload data on Linux for backups to multiple clouds](https://superuser.com/questions/614505/looking-for-linux-friendly-software-that-will-compress-encrypt-split-and-uplo/614507#614507)

Could someone help me figure out what happened?

Comment: Which ID provider are you using?

Comment: I had signed up just for StackExchange

Comment: Edit: I remember using the "create account" option that didn't require the use of OpenID but I think I ended up connecting my google account to it.